# ATmega32U4 can not DFU mode (Reset)

Tags: atmega, qmk

[image]I made a DIY PCB using ATmega32U4-MU.

I'm trying to flash an ATmega32U4-MU using QMK (QMK MSYS), but I can't get it into DFU mode. Please give me any suggestions.

1. Windows recognizes ATmega32U4 (ATm32U4DFU), so I think you can flash it if the reset works.

2, I'm using a 5.1k Reset register, but many YouTube tutorials use a 10k register...

3. +3.3V is not used. Connect only +5V

I am an amateur at electronics work and have no idea what the problem is. It would be very helpful if you could give me some hints.

thank you !